# c# regex clarification

Tags: c#, regex

I'm having trouble understanding the reason for the output of the following code

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        var p1 = "txtbox"; 
        CheckMatch(p1);
        p1 = "txtbox_asd";
        CheckMatch(p1);
        p1 = "txtbox_asdf";
        CheckMatch(p1);
        p1 = "txtbox_asd2";
        CheckMatch(p1);
    }

    public static void CheckMatch(string p1)
    {
        var reg = new Regex(@"txtbox");
        if (!reg .IsMatch(p1))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{p1} doesn't match");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{p1} matches");
        }
    }
```

All of the cases are returning 'matches', whereas I am only expecting the first case to match. Is there a way to have it s.t. only the first case matches?

Comment: If you want full string to mach, then you have to put `^` and `$` to your regex, i.e. `^txtbox$`. Otherwise with `txtbox` regex if your text contains `txtbox`, it will be successfully matched.

Comment: Additionally to what UlugbekUmirov correctly mentioned you can simplify that to `p1 == "textbox"` in that case.

Comment: What is the point of using a Regex if you are only looking for a specific string and not for a rule?

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov Thanks, that works. If you could write an answer, I'd be happy to accept.

Comment: @AviMeltser It's because the above is just one simple example. I'd also like proper matches on ex. textbox.*, I just couldn't understand why all cases of textbox_ was matching what I thought should only match if the rule was textbox.*